# How can I group amount of sales for the last 30days grouped on a daily basis

Tags: sql-server

I am using `Microsoft SQL Server` and am trying to figure out how to get the total numbers sales for the last 30days on a daily basis.

```
declare @startperiod date;
declare @endperiod date;
set @startperiod = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0)   --First day of 3 months ago
set @endperiod = getdate()-1  

select distinct

    sum(salesamount) as TotalSales

from sales

where salesdate between getdate()-30 and getdate()-1
```

The above will only give me the total of sales for the past 30 days as at yesterday. What I would like is the following:

```
#Sales_Last30Days | Date as at

120                 19/11/2020
140                 18/11/2020
```

Basically what I am showing in the above table is that 30days before till the 19/11/2020 we have 120 sales, similarly 30days before the 18/11/2020 till the 18/11/2020 we have 140 sales.

I hope someone can help because I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: Hint - "on a daily basis" means you need a value for EVERY DATE. That requires a "list of dates" and you reference that date in a group by clause. "list of dates" is short-hand for a calendar table - simple web searching will find many discussions about generating that information.

Comment: @SMor - I have managed to create a table with the "list of dates" however i am not sure how can add the number of sales on a daily basis for the last 30 days?